# Merging records with left joins producing too many records

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 10.1

I have the following SQL command that is *almost* good enough --  *but not quite*. (The title is the best I could come up with :))

The idea is to have a speciality which can have 0,1, or more offices. Each office can have 0,1, or more consultants (i.e., lastname/firstname).

The goal is to always show the speciality name on each record.
If there is any office for that speciality, then that office needs to appear (without duplication) with that speciality. (It is possible that the same office can be listed with more then one speciality). 
If there is any consultant with the office listed, then the consultant should be listed with the office.
An office that has a consultant should always be listed with that consultant.

By the above requirements, the following SQL essentially produces *too many* records. That is, in studying the output:

1. Line #5 ('AAAMMM') should be dropped since line #4 ('AAAMMM') has a consultant assigned to the same office with the same speciality and Line #5 has nulls for the consultant.
2. Line #12 and Line #14 should be dropped. Again, both of these lines have null for the consultant for the same office in which the corresponding line above it does have a consultant.

How can I write the SQL to correctly produce the desired results?  (Or would a program approach be better?)

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 select s.speciality_name, f.office_name, f.street, f.city, f.state, f.zipcode, f.phone, f.fax, cs.lastname, cs.firstname, 0 as status, s.recid
    from speciality s
         left join office_speciality os on os.speciality_recid = s.recid
         left join office f on f.recid = os.office_recid
         left join consultant_office co on co.office_recid = f.recid
         left join consultant cs on cs.recid = co.consultant_recid and  cs.speciality_recid = s.recid
    group by speciality_name, office_name, street, city, state, zipcode, phone, fax, lastname, firstname, s.recid
    order by s.speciality_name, f.office_name, cs.lastname, cs.firstname;
```

The resulting table appears as:
[image]

Edit: Using the below code still results in too many partial rows being generated when a complete row exists. Line #12 and Line #14:

```
with office_speciality_consultants AS (
  select distinct on (os.office_recid, os.speciality_recid, cs.recid)
      os.office_recid, os.speciality_recid,
      f.office_name, f.street, f.city, f.state, f.zipcode, f.phone, f.fax,
      cs.lastname, cs.firstname
  from office_speciality os
    join office f on f.recid = os.office_recid
    left join consultant_office co on co.office_recid = f.recid
    left join consultant cs on cs.recid = co.consultant_recid
                                and cs.speciality_recid = os.speciality_recid
  order by os.office_recid, os.speciality_recid, cs.recid, f.office_name, cs.lastname, cs.firstname
)
select
  s.speciality_name,
  ofc.office_name, ofc.street, ofc.city, ofc.state, ofc.zipcode, ofc.phone, ofc.fax,
  ofc.lastname, ofc.firstname,
  0 as status, s.recid
from speciality s
  join office_speciality_consultants ofc ON ofc.speciality_recid = s.recid
order by s.speciality_name, ofc.office_name;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that helped. The basic problems come down to:

1. Partial data is allowed and should be preserved, except when their is more information. Thas is, if an office is available for a speciality, then any listing for that speciality should have that office and a record with a null office for that speciality should not be listed. The same holds when a consultant is available for an office--a record with a null consultant should not be presented when that office is presented.
2. Observation of the first results, showed that unnecessary records were being produced with null information.
3. There can be any number of specialities, offices per speciality, and consultants per office--without duplication.

Using CTE's provides a simple step approach to solving the problem.

```
with t0 as (    -- get all completed records. This table to be used for lookup of consultant_recid.
select s.recid as speciality_recid, f.recid as office_recid, cs.recid as consultant_recid
from speciality s
        join office_speciality os on os.speciality_recid = s.recid
        join office f on f.recid = os.office_recid
        join consultant_office co on co.office_recid = f.recid
        join consultant cs on cs.recid = co.consultant_recid and  cs.speciality_recid = s.recid 
),
t1 as (         -- get speciality and office without duplication. 
                -- office_speciality is UNIQUE (office_recid, speciality_recid)
select s.recid as speciality_recid, os.office_recid as office_recid
from speciality s
        left join office_speciality os on os.speciality_recid = s.recid
group by s.recid, os.office_recid   
),
t2 as (         -- add consultants to record when available.
                -- left join used to fill in consultant when available, null otherwise.
select t1.speciality_recid, t1.office_recid, t0.consultant_recid 
    from t1
    left join t0 on t0.speciality_recid = t1.speciality_recid and t0.office_recid = t1.office_recid
)
select s.speciality_name, f.office_name, f.street, f.city, f.state, f.zipcode, f.phone, f.fax, cs.lastname, cs.firstname, 0 as status
from t2
join speciality s on s.recid = t2.speciality_recid
join office f on f.recid = t2.office_recid
left join consultant cs on cs.recid = t2.consultant_recid and cs.speciality_recid = s.recid
order by s.speciality_name, f.office_name, cs.lastname;
```

By using left joins to extend records with information, when available (null otherwise), and by preventing duplication in t1, all the problems are simply resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If we need all offices, but just one consultant from office then I believe following should work

```
with office_speciality_consultants AS (
  select distinct on (os.office_recid, os.speciality_recid, cs.recid)
      os.office_recid, os.speciality_recid,
      f.office_name, f.street, f.city, f.state, f.zipcode, f.phone, f.fax,
      cs.lastname, cs.firstname
  from office_speciality os
    join office f on f.recid = os.office_recid
    left join consultant_office co on co.office_recid = f.recid
    left join consultant cs on cs.recid = co.consultant_recid
                                and cs.speciality_recid = os.speciality_recid
  order by os.office_recid, os.speciality_recid, cs.recid, f.office_name, cs.lastname, cs.firstname
)
select
  s.speciality_name,
  ofc.office_name, ofc.street, ofc.city, ofc.state, ofc.zipcode, ofc.phone, ofc.fax,
  ofc.lastname, ofc.firstname,
  0 as status, s.recid
from speciality s
  join office_speciality_consultants ofc ON ofc.speciality_recid = s.recid
order by ofc.office_name;
```

Comment: Offices can have 0,1, or many consultants. I need to show all the consultants for an office, but just the office if no consultants are available. :)

Comment: Upon further checking, this fails when there is more then one non-null consultant in an office.

Comment: Edited my answer to show all consultants, pay attention to `cs.recid` added to `distinct on (..)` and `order by`

Comment: Great effort. The changes do now correctly capture multiple offices. However, it also restores the null records from the original left joins--back to square one. :)

Comment: You mean the case when speciality doesn't have an office? If so, just replace `left join` with `join` and that's it. Edited the answer

Comment: The database here is replicating a wpf treeview where  partial information is allowed. Considering a row to be partial when nulls are present, and complete when no nulls are present, the goal is to only drop rows when a more complete row exists. Please see updated question. Sincere thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Rows #12 and 14 have null values because `last_name` and `first_name` are nullable, right?

Comment: The database will allow an office to be related to the speciality--without knowledge of any consultant in that office. When a consultant has been established, then only the record with the consultant need be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last `LEFT JOIN` With `INNER JOIN`

```
select s.speciality_name, f.office_name, f.street, f.city, f.state, f.zipcode, f.phone, f.fax, cs.lastname, cs.firstname, 0 as status, s.recid
    from speciality s
         left join office_speciality os on os.speciality_recid = s.recid
         left join office f on f.recid = os.office_recid
         left join consultant_office co on co.office_recid = f.recid
         inner join consultant cs on cs.recid = co.consultant_recid and  cs.speciality_recid = s.recid
    group by speciality_name, office_name, street, city, state, zipcode, phone, fax, lastname, firstname, s.recid
    order by s.speciality_name, f.office_name, cs.lastname, cs.firstname;
```

Comment: Nope...With the inner join, offices that do not have consultants are also lost. I need to be able to show specialities with offices that do not have consultants as well as offices that do have consultants. :)